# Chart.js : add space or margin top on bubble chart area

Tags: chart.js

With bubble chart, is there a way in the options to increase the space or adding margin between the labels categories and the chart area. My question is probably trivial but I'm not found solutions until now except to increase scales that depending maximum x, y in datasets.
Thank you in advance...[image]